# Learning English - How to retell this story

Tags: speech

I'm Serbian and I'm currently learning English. I'm searching for someone who can retell this story for me. I want to see the style of retelling in English. Please, if you can take a minute, help me see the retelling of this story in English. I chose this story from a book I'm reading:

[image]

Comment: Retell?  As in, you want someone to tell/write the same story but use different words?

Comment: Yes, I don't know exact phrase for this.

Comment: *Retell* is the right word, but it's not something that we typically do here.  Why do you want someone to retell it?  Is there something in the story that you do not understand?

Comment: I know how to retell dialog, but in this story it look like this story is already retold

Comment: I think what the poster is asking for is an interpertation

Comment: I just want to learn how to retell stories of this type

Comment: What do you mean by "retell"? What do you hope to end up with? Perhaps you could retell a single sentence like the last ("Paul helped move everything...") so that we can see what sort of thing you hope to end up with. However, it's **very** likely that the question is off-topic; ELU deals with *specific* points of uncertainty; we don't go in for long passages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Narrative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/narrative) - the representation in art of an event or story.

[Нарратив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Comment: you may want to check your spelling.

Comment: @ab2 - oops....thnx!